# Why add nameserver and NS record

Tags: tcp, dns

When I register a domain and get hosing on different company I have to *add* the hosting company nameserver. This might sound reasonable.

BUT, in the hosing company cpanel there would be NS records with their nameservers, why is this needed ? Also the same if I leave the default nameservers in my domain there are NS records in the DNS section pointing to the same nsx.blabla.com.

Here is a photo explaining what I mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGy9O.png

So when a request to my domain is made, a final A record is needed. In order to obtain that record, the requester looks up for A record by asking whom? The nameseever added in the liat above or the nameserver in the NS record ?

Answer (score 0):

> So when a request to my domain is made, a final A record is needed. In order to obtain that record, the requester looks up for A record by asking whom?

By asking domain NS where pointed the NS records then ask this server(ip on which NS records are pointing) where pointed domain A or AAAA record.